# Access iframe src without ID

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an app thats being loaded inside of an iframe. Is there a way to access the src tag inside the iframw from the app without knowing the iframe ID?

For example:

```
<iframe src="www.exampleURL.com">
```

How would I go about getting [www.exampleURL.com](http://www.exampleURL.com) in my app? Is an ID required to achieve this?
Sorry if its a stupid question, have not worked with iframes much.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

iframes are just another kind of DOM element, so all the usual traversal and selection methods are available; this can be easy or difficult depending on the structure of the rest of the page and the number of similar elements you need to dig through.  For example, if it's the only iframe on the page you could use getElementsByTagName:

```js
let url = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src

console.log(url)
```

```html
<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```